# convert Linux date to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z' format

Tags: linux, date, datetime, smartsheet-api-2.0

I need to parameter-ize a datetime value with an objective of passing to a constructed URI to make a Smartsheet API call to get data (i.e. sheets) changed in last 24 hours.

I want to use Linux `date` command as I can do something like `date -d '1 day ago' %F` to get the output of a day before today.  How can I use the date command to convert the value to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` format to get something like `2018-01-01T00:00:00-07:00`?

If the value is not in this particular format, then Smartsheet API complains:

```
HTTP_01 - Error fetching resource. Status: 400 Reason: 
Bad Request : { "errorCode" : 1018, "message" : "The value '/home/my/path/to/param_file/Sysdate' was not valid for the parameter modifiedSince.", "refId" : "1xqawd3s94f4y" }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: @jww, did you downvote all the answers? If yes, why?

Answer (score 32):

To output date in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, you'll probably want to use `-I[FMT]`/`--iso-8601[=FMT]` option, if your [`date`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) supports it (GNU/Linux version does). The `FMT` is basically a resolution, and in your case you'll want to use `s` for seconds:

```
$ date -Is
2018-03-09T09:28:14+01:00
```

The alternative (for [POSIX `date`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html), including [BSD/OSX `date`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?date)) is to explicitly specify the format and output the time in `UTC` time zone (`-u` flag):

```
$ date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
2018-03-09T08:28:14Z
```

Note the importance of `-u` and the explicit `Z` we can append in that case. Without `-u`, we would need to output the exact time zone in `+hh:mm` format, but POSIX `date` provides support only for time zone name output (`%Z`). GNU `date` extends the format set with `%:z` which outputs the numeric time zone, but if already using GNU `date`, the first approach with `-Is` is simpler.

Answer (score 5):

When calling `date` in your shell use the following format

```
date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%SZ"
```

> 2018-03-09T07-44-39Z

Comment: Please note this prints the correct time *only if your local timezone is UTC*. The problem with this command is that it always prints the local time and appends the hardcoded/fixed timezone, Z. Check out the `-u` flag (see my answer).

Answer (score 4):

To be shortest as possible :

`date -u +"%FT%TZ"` for UTC

`date +"%FT%TZ"` for locale's time

Comment: This is wrong - the `Z` is an indicator that it is a UTC timestamp. It produces a valid format but changes its meaning.

Comment: jadjay's response is helpful, but as @Waddles points out, it's not entirely correct. 

From the `man date` output on Ubuntu: 
*%F* gives us the full date; just like `%+4Y-%m-%d` does. 
*T* gives us the character "T".  
*%T* gives us the time; same as `%H:%M:%S` . 
*Z* gives us the character "Z".   

This leaves us with: `2022-07-09T12:24:06Z` , which is in local time, not Zulu. The *-u* converts to UTC (a.k.a. zulu time). 
 
Read the man page `man date` for a lot more info.

Comment: All right, all right, all right gentlemen :

Let say I wrote 

`date -u +"%FT%TZ"` for UTC
`date +"%FT%T"` for localtime

Answer (score 2):

Use this alias in the `bash_profile`:

```
alias utc='date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"'
```

Then, you can run it like:

```
$ utc
```

The output will be:

```
$ 2021-04-15T01:36:31Z
```